# issues with installing react native, npm install -g expo-cli gives warnings

Tags: react-native, npm

I'm trying to install Expo CLI to [set up the development environment for React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) but I keep getting this warning when I enter "npm install -g expo-cli" into my terminal:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=12 <=16' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v18.2.0', npm: '8.9.0' }
```

Previously, trying to install Expo CLI with npm would throw errors like

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-dKBr48UN'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Then I tried the NVM solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/how-to-fix-npm-throwing-error-without-sudo/24404451#24404451) which asked me to uninstall node and then install NVM so that doing things like writing in my npm directory wouldn't ask for permission, but now I'm unsure what to do.

edit:

I followed [this website](https://chamikakasun.medium.com/how-to-manage-multiple-node-versions-in-macos-2021-guide-5065f32cb63b) to change my node version to `v14.19.3` but now there are these warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.8: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
/Users/zoeylee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/bin/expo -> /Users/zoeylee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/Users/zoeylee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/bin/expo-cli -> /Users/zoeylee/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.3/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.5.2 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I'm a new user and programmer so any advice/help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `18.2.0`, but the message says it requires `>=12 <=16` (greater than 12 and less than 16. Not `18.2.0` or greater.

If it's your package.json with the engines field causing this issue, change it to say 12.0.0 or greater:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: I changed it to v14.19.3 but now there are different warnings